# The text is not output to the form

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new to react native, trying to write a small project (notebook). I implemented the buttons, they all work, but when I save an entry to the form, nothing is displayed and does not give errors.

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Modal, Text, View, ScrollView, TextInput, Image, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Formik } from 'formik';

export default function App() {
  const [news, setnews] = useState([
    {name: '', text: ''}
  ]);
  const addArtical = (artical) => {
  setnews((list) => {
  artical.key = Math.random().toString();
  return[
    artical,
    ...list
  ]
});
setModalWindow(false);
  }
  const [modalWindow, setModalWindow] = useState(false);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.title}>Main tasks:</Text>
       <ScrollView horizontal={true} showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}>
       <View style={styles.up}>
        <View style={styles.cub}></View>
        <View style={styles.cub}></View>
        <View style={styles.cub}></View>
        <View style={styles.cub}></View>
        <View style={styles.cub}></View>
        <View style={styles.cub}></View>
      </View>
     </ScrollView>
      <ScrollView vertical={true} showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>
        <View style={styles.all}>
        <TextInput style={styles.d} placeholder='  Search'></TextInput>
        <Text style={styles.titletwo}>Other tasks:</Text>
      <Ionicons style={styles.ic} name="add" size={30} color="black" onPress={() => setModalWindow(true)}/>
      </View>
      <Modal visible={modalWindow}>
      <Ionicons style={styles.ic} name="close" size={30} color="black" onPress={() => setModalWindow(false)}/>
      <View>
        <Formik initialValues={{name: '', text: ''}} onSubmit={(values, clean) => {
          addArtical(values);
          clean.resetForm();
        }}>
          {(props) => (
            <View >
              <TextInput value={props.values.name} placeholder='Name' onChangeText={props.handleChange('name')}/>
              <TextInput value={props.values.text} multiline placeholder='Text' onChangeText={props.handleChange('text')}/>
              <Button title='Add' onPress={props.handleSubmit}/>
            </View>
          )}
        </Formik>
      </View>
      </Modal>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Read more: I click add entry, a field opens with the addition of text, fill in the field with the necessary information, save, everything is successful, but my entry is nowhere

Comment: i'm not sure where the problem is but i cannot see where you are are trying to render your news

Comment: There should be something like `news.map(article =><div>{article.name}</div>)`

Comment: Could you tell me which part of the code you mean?

Comment: Ok you input a news article right ? and you want to display it after writing it . There should be code where you display it